How to Calculate the Exact Timing for CV charging mode in a lithium cell?
We charge our Battery with CC method upto 80%. We got the time for it. Capacity/Ah. Now we switch to CV method for rest of the 20%. How to calculate Time for that Dropping Current?

You don't. You measure voltage and cut the charge when a threshold is reached.
